# What is the reason for this mysterous SQL output ( using MariaDB )?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is a query I inputted , admittedly a random tweak , into a test box in the website [SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations)   :

```
SELECT title || 'fo'
FROM movie
WHERE title IS NOT NULL
AND title like '%he%';
```

And it returns unusual output that looks like this :

```
title || fo
--------------------
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
/* etc etc just 0's and 1's */
```

Whereas if I just use the following query :

```
SELECT title 
FROM movie
WHERE title IS NOT NULL
AND title like '%he%';
```

then I will ge tthe very reasonable output I expected :

```
title
--------------------
Gone with the End
Dr. doLittle
Con Air.
/* et etc more movi */
```

So I think the back-end on this website uses something called MariaDB ( a branch of MySQL , perhaps ? ).

why would I get the output of `0's` and `1's` only , just by conccatenating the title with a string ?

To be precise, it's the 6th one -  What is the id of the film 'Casablanca' .
thanks

Comment: MySQL is returning the true/false value of `title || 'fo'`

Comment: Concatenation in MySQL is `CONCAT(title, 'fo')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `||` is the logical `or` operation -- not string concatenation.  So, your select is really:

```
select (title OR fo)
```

which just checks that one or the other is "true" (non-zero).

The list of operators is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html).

You can change this behavior by setting the mode `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)).